# Venn diagram (image/label/shape) on android screen with its zones clickable

Tags: java, android, image-processing, data-visualization, venn-diagram

I need to create an Image on android screen. It should be a Venn diagram with each of its zones clickable. The image should be zoomable.

```
The Solutions I could think of was:
```

1. Using java to render the whole diagram (I find this hard and less user friendly) any APIs?
2. a broken image of Venn diagram  in to small sub-pictures (or simply pictures) put together that looks as one diagram but in reality individual pictures which are labelled and each clickable
3. Or maybe if this is some how possible using the XML in Android ?

> Note: The Venn diagram doesn't have to be in circles, it can be square
>   or what ever. as long as it can be zoomed so each of its zones are
>   visible and clickable.

Any guidance, suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really good widget(single class) that helps you make any image muli-clickable. They have some good notes on how to use their code as well.

The widget has a similar approach as Image mapping in html. The good thing about this widget is that the image can be zoomed and it will not lose the coordinates or areas associated to each distinct clickable area.

[Here](http://catchthecows.com/?p=113) is the link to their website. the guy who made the widget apparently had similar problem and came up with this widget.